# EmberJS dynamic observers at run-time?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Given the following models:

(note: these are simplified for illustration purposes)

```
App.CustomerOrder = DS.Model.extend({
  deliveries: DS.hasMany('delivery'),
  total: DS.attr('number')
});

App.Delivery = DS.Model.extend({
  orderlines: DS.hasMany('orderline')
});

App.OrderLine = DS.Model.extend({
  productid: DS.attr('string'),
  qtyordered: DS.attr('number')
});
```

When the app first loads I'm querying an API that sends me information about which dependencies should trigger an update. So for example it'll send me something like:

```
CustomerOrder: ["deliveries", "deliveries.orderlines", "deliveries.orderlines.qtyordered"...]
```

..means, if deliveries are added/deleted from a customerorder or if lines are added/deleted from a delivery attached to a customer order or if the qtyordered on an orderline on a delivery attached to a customer order, then what the API expects is for me to serialize CustomerOrder (along with the entire chain of relationships) and sent to an 'update' service (i.e. server/customerorder/updates type thing) that will run various routines and fill-in pieces of data and send the entire chain of objects back.

For illustration purposes I've put a simple example on here of an ordertotal (I realize this is easily calculated client-side but there's a bunch of other stuff that would be duplication of code from the server). So, if the qtyordered on an orderline changes, I need to send the customerorder instance to the server, where it will update my total field.

One of the challenges is that I can't hard code that dependency list by setting up observer functions with .observes() type stuff, it has to be done dynamically after that dependency data is loaded (presumably using addObserver). The other is that observers wont dig multiple layers deep like that.

I've tried using a mix-in to the models that overrides the init function and does exactly that.

```
clientchangeset: DS.attr('raw'),

init: function() {
  this._super.apply(this, arguments);
  var className = this.auth.camelizedModelString(this.constructor.toString());
  var watchlist = this.auth.dependencies[className] || null;

  var self = this;
  watchlist.forEach(function(watch) {
    if(watch.hasOwnProperty('attributeName') && watch.hasOwnProperty('collectionFlag')) {
      // {attributeName: attributeName, collectionFlag: collectionFlag}
      if(watch['collectionFlag']) {
        console.log(className+'.addObserver('+watch['attributeName']+'.@each.clientchangeset)');
        self.addObserver(watch['attributeName']+'.@each.clientchangeset', null, 'updateChangelist');
      } else {
        console.log(className+'.addObserver('+watch['attributeName']+')');
        self.addObserver(watch['attributeName'], null, 'updateChangelist');
      }  
    }
  });
},
```

This appears to work, but only one layer deep. For completeness, heres the updateChangelist function:

```
updateChangelist: function(src, field, value) { //jshint ignore:line

  if(this.get('pauseUpdates')) {
    return;
  }
  var className = this.auth.camelizedModelString(this.constructor.toString());

  var oldclientchangeset = this.get('clientchangeset') || [];
  console.log('Before: '+className+'.[clientchangeset]= '+oldclientchangeset);
  oldclientchangeset.pushObject(field);
  this.set('clientchangeset', oldclientchangeset);
  console.log('After: '+className+'.[clientchangeset]= '+oldclientchangeset);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in general the way I got this to work was to create the observers as indicated, but the handlers simply update a property called '_needsUpdate' on each level of the relationships whenever they are triggered. '_needsUpdate' is just a date so when triggered I do:

```
this.set('_needsUpdate', +new Date());
```

Then when setting up observers at each level for that level's children, I just set up a single observer to look at child.@each._needsUpdate.