# Need a strategy for implementing a partial update service call without re-inventing the wheel

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My backend has some cool functionality that I'm struggling with implementing. Easier to explain with an example...

Say you have an order, with order lines (defined as hasMany) and products attached that the user is currently editing and they change the price on a line. Functionally you'd want to recalculate the sales tax as an example.

My backend allows me to package-up and send this transient object (along with a list of changed fields) and will determine what needs to be altered on the object tree (without actually persisting that object yet). What it returns is a sparsely-populated object with the values that have been changed server-side.

So, if I have something like this:

```
{
  orderid: '12345',
  taxamt: 0,
  lines: [
    {
      id: 1,
      product: 'ABC',
      price: 99.99
    }
  ]
}
```

And then let's say, the user updates the line price. If I send this to the backend:

```
{
  orderid: '12345',
  taxamt: 0,
  lines: [
    {
      id: 1,
      product: 'ABC',
      price: 89.99
    }
  ],
  changelist: ['lines.price']
}
```

... I'll get back something like this:

```
{
  orderid: '12345',
  taxamt: 12.00,
}
```

...that is, I'll get enough to uniquely identify each object and then only the properties that were updated server-side.

I've got the first half of this implemented, but handling the return is proving to be difficult. I've got it partially working but it sure feels like I'm re-implementing a ton of what ember data is already doing.

Given that the server may add or delete relationship objects and may alter any property at any level, what's a good approach that leverages the existing framework the best?

UPDATE: Please note that I'm not an ember data noob :) I have find and save working just fine with custom serializers, etc. to deal with non-conforming JSON.

I cannot change the back-end as we already have an existing client app working with it in production that I cannot disrupt.

The scenario I'm describing here is neither a find nor a save - **I need to create something custom**. The example is meant to portray a new order that I've just started creating on the client. The server has no knowledge of this object yet. In my example, to calculate tax in near-real-time, I call the "update" endpoint to let the server do that calculation on a transient object that it will not save the DB yet but will do any calculations and processing and business logic on the server and send the changes back to the client. The reason it works this way is to remove business logic like tax calculations from the client application (or even needing to know when to do the calculations).

Comment: I understand ember data well enough that I have standard find and save working just fine with custom serializers, etc. What I'm describing here is neither a find nor a save. I need to implement something custom but I'm looking for guidance on the best approach. What I'm describing here can be for a new object that I'm still working with in the client that will be sent to the server for updates (i.e. like my calculating tax example) that will not be saved on the server yet (i'll use standard save for that). This is done to side-step the client having to do business logic like that.

Answer (score 0):

Your case seems to be a standard one for ember data. Have you read this one: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/connecting-to-an-http-server/ ?

Read about URL and JSON conventions and you should end up using standard this.store.find('order'), `this.store.find('order', id)` or `newOrder.save()` methods.

Given the JSON you provided, `changelist` doesn't seem to be needed on the frontend side, so unless you really need it on the backend side, I wouldn't put it there.

Since you have a full control over the backend I would alter `orderid` to `id` - then you don't have to change anything on ember's side.

The response could be the full record response. If you're always consistent with your data, then it's easier. Moreover, I would change a bit the structure (see below).

What should work in this case would be sth like:

```
var OrderModel = DS.Model.extend({
  taxamt: DS.attr('number'),
  lines: DS.hasMany('line')
});

var LineModel = DS.Model.extend({
  product: DS.attr('string'),
  price: DS.attr('number')
});
```

then, if you want to get one `order` (using `this.store.find('order', 12345)`, your JSON is expected to look like:

```
{
  "order": {
    "id": '12345',
    "taxamt": 0,
    "lines": [1]
  },
  "line": [{
    "id": 1,
    "product": 'ABC',
    "price": 99.99
  }]
}
```

If you don't want to change the behaviour of your backend, you can always use the serializer and its `normalizePayload` method. Simplified example:

```
var OrderSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  normalizePayload: function(payload) {
    return {
      "order": payload
    };
  }
});
```

which would accept this payload:

```
{
  "id": 12345,
  "taxamt": 0
}
```

and transform it to:

```
{
  "order": {
    "id": 12345,
    "taxamt": 0
  }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't clear though. I can't use find in the standard sense because the order doesn't yet exist on the backend and I'd need to use find later on in the standard fashion for cases when it does.

Comment: It cut me off. Sorry. I have find and save working for this end point with custom serializers to deal with the non standard JSON structure. I need to implement something similar to find that mimics what happens on the return trip.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to bite the bullet and spend some quality time with the ember data source code. :)

So turns out that this was pretty easy to do....that is once you wrap your arms around the guts of ember data and what it's doing.

I'd already implemented the observer side to detect and kick off the update call (see [EmberJS dynamic observers at run-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26807318/emberjs-dynamic-observers-at-run-time))

All this did was kick off a debounced $.ajax call on my application adapter. The trick was, how to handle the response.

Turns out, all I needed to really do was....

```
getUpdates: function() {
    var store = this.autoUpdateContext.store;
    var type = this.autoUpdateContext.type;
    var record = this.autoUpdateContext.record;
    var className = this.autoUpdateContext.className;
    var url = this.autoUpdateContext.url;
    var self = this;

    var serializedRecord = self._serializeForService(record);
    var data = {};

    data[className] = serializedRecord;
    data = self._mergeParams(data);

    var serializer = store.serializerFor(record.constructor.typeKey);

    var also_managing = serializer.get('also_managing');
    if(also_managing !== null) {
      data['also_managing'] = JSON.stringify(also_managing);
    }

    Ember.$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
      data: data
    }).then(function(data) {
      //THIS IS THE IMPORTANT STEP HERE...THESE NEXT TWO LINES
      var payload = serializer.extract(store, type, data, record.get('id'), 'updateRecord');
      return store.push(type, payload);
    }, function(jqXHR) {
      console.log('Error getting updates'+jqXHR);
    });
  },
```

So calling serializer.extract will run through all of the extractMeta and normalizer stuff that I needed it to, along with the EmbeddedRecords mix-in stuff doing its magic. The 'udpateRecord' bit isn't super important but it comes closest to being the idea of what this is doing.

store.push can apparently handle the sparsely populated return value just fine...sweet!

This needs to be cleaned up some more and I'll likely end up moving this to the store in the end, but it *appears* to work.